# Getting null as response in lamda function, But data is not getting inserted on dynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AMS and i am going throw an online coarse.
I am trying to insert data into the dynamoDB table user-data.
Given dynamoDB full access permission in IAM roles.

My lambda function looks like below,

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

console.log(event);

const itemData = {
    Item : {
        "UserId" : {
            S : "BasavarajHadimani"
        },
        "Age" : {
            N : "26"
        },
        "Height" : {
            N : "112"
        },
        "Salary" : {
            N : "2500"
        }
    },
    TableName : "user-table"
};

dynamoDB.putItem(itemData, function(err, resp){
    if(err){
           console.log(err)
           callback(null, err);   
    }else{
           console.log(resp)
           callback(null, resp);
    }
})

};
```

And getting response as below,

```
Response:
null

Request ID:"XXXXXXXXXXXX"

Function logs:
START RequestId: XXXXXXXXXX Version: $LATEST
2020-08-22T05:55:47.385Z    XXXXXXXXX   INFO    { key1: 
'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }
END RequestId: XXXXXXXXXX
REPORT RequestId: XXXXXXXXXX    Duration: 534.92 ms Billed Duration: 
600 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 87 MB  Init Duration: 446.75 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

console.log(event);

const itemData = {
    Item : {
        "UserId" : {
            S : "BasavarajHadimani"
        },
        "Age" : {
            N : "26"
        },
        "Height" : {
            N : "112"
        },
        "Salary" : {
            N : "2500"
        }
    },
    TableName : "user-table"
};

dynamoDB.putItem(itemData, function(err, resp){
    if(err){
           console.log(err)
    }else{
           console.log(resp)
    }
})

};
```

[image]

Comment: yes it worked, but using async/ arrow function was the reason why i was not getting?

Comment: Some `node.js` expert can comment on it but I was more into fixing your issue.

Comment: @BasavarajHadimani the problem is that you can't randomly mix async/promises with callbacks. The alternate solution would have been to keep your async handler but promisify the DynamoDB call using something like `dynamoDB.putItem(itemData).promise();` as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html.